# Better std::find on a collection of pointers and comparing dereferenced value to a const reference value

Tags: c++, search, find, std

Originally I had a member that was a `std::vector<Point>` with a method that did this:

```
bool Spline::Intersects(const Point& point) const {
    return std::find(this->_result_points.begin(), _result_points.end(), point) != _result_points.end();
}
```

The design changed and `std::vector<Point>` became `std::vector<Point*>` and the previous method no longer worked and I had to change it to:

```
bool Spline::Intersects(const Point& point) const {
    for(std::vector<Point*>::const_iterator _iter = _result_points.begin(); _iter != _result_points.end(); ++_iter) {
        if(*(*_iter) == point) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does `std::find` perform the same linear search? If so, is there a faster/better/less gross way to do this (especially the double de-reference of the iterator)?

There are other places in the code that the `std::find(this->_result_points.begin(), _result_points.end(), point) != _result_points.end();` (or similar, but opposite results) is performed and I would rather not have to use that slow linear for loop.

Comment: iterators must be dereferenced twice. It's how c++ is. Iterator acts like a pointer. Your vector contains Point pointers, so an iterator will act like a pointer to a pointer, so it needs to be dereferenced twice.

Comment: @Adrian: Whether iterators are implemented with pointers is implementation-defined.

Comment: There's no "double de-reference of the iterator". You're storing pointers in a standard container, which is silly.

Comment: @Lightness: Irrespective of implementation, "iterator acts like pointer". The iterator interface is inspired by pointers. Whether it is silly to store pointers in a standard container depends on the lifetime of the referands. Sometimes it is not silly.

Comment: @SteveJessop: `std::vector<T*>` is silly. We have wrappers for that that make life a lot easier, in the rare case that you _really_ need it. And if you can cite "iterator acts like pointer" then that'd be grand; doesn't really matter what inspired it. I find myself inspired by the moon quite often but I'm not made of cheese

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just curious, why do you think vector<Point*> is silly?

Comment: @Lightness: you're mistaken as to silliness. The significance of the inspiration is that by design, the interator interface is an abstraction of the pointer interface (or just part of it, depending on the iterator category). That's what "acts like" means, "has the same interface". It doesn't mean "is one". If you act like the moon, then whether you're really made of cheese or not is an implementation detail, but you'll look like you are.

Comment: @Adrian: because `boost::ptr_vector` exists

Comment: @Steve: No, but standard containers are designed to own their "elements", and `ptr_vector` making that work despite the added layer of indirection makes sense to me. Yes, there are times when you _want_ a collection of pointers to shared stuff, but then why are you using raw pointers? To me, it just comes back to a combination of slightly bad practices culminating in one ugly type.

Comment: @Steve and Lightness: The pointers are for interfacing with an Observer pattern that registers pointers to objects (but does not own them). Allocating the points on the stack instead of the heap caused dangling pointers.

Comment: @Casey: Lightness would prefer you to heap-allocate everything, unfortunately he thinks stack allocation is "silly" ;-) So, heap-allocate the points, use `shared_ptr` everywhere, and then you're covered in the case that your vector somehow outlives those stack-allocated objects. Defining the vector in a more-inner scope than the points prevents that happening at all, but a lot of faff with `shared_ptr`, just in case it does happen, is less "silly". Or anyway less specialized to your real situation.

Comment: @Steve: I don't want the Subject to own the pointers as `shared_ptr` will cause. It is just a list of pointers that the Subject calls methods of the Observers. It's kind of like having a list of movies you own. As you buy/sell movies, you add/remove them to/from the list. Therefore any movie on the list can have `watch()` called on it; any movie not on the list can't. If you remove it from the list, should that mean the movie no longer exists? No, it just can't be watched. [/Bad analogy]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `find` does the same linear search.

You could hide the loop and the double indirection by using `find_if` with a suitable predicate: `bool operator()(Point* ptr) { return *ptr == point; }`

If you want to avoid linear searches, you need to change the way the data is stored. For example keeping the vector sorted would allow `std::binary_search`, which is faster than `std::find`. That's sorted by the value pointed to, *not* sorted by pointer value, so you'd need to pass a comparator to `std::sort` etc. Or you could use an entirely different container: perhaps one of `(unordered_)(multi)set`.

Comment: The class is a facade of the Allegro 4.2 calls to `calc_spline` and `spline`. Allegro returns an array of `int`s for the x values and an array of `int`s for the y values. I would GUESS that I could sort them by x value since it is a bezier(sp?) curve and all points would theoretically be different. Thanks.

Comment: `std::binary_search` is the most poorly named function ever. Most people think of a binary search algorithm as returning the found item, but `binary_search` just returns a bool - "yup, it's there". Use `std::lower_bound` instead.

Comment: @Mark: Normally yes, but here all the result is used for is to compare it to the end iterator. So `binary_search` is exactly the tool for this job, whatever its name *should* be. It is almost redundant, but not quite since in the case where there are multiple equal values in the range, `binary_search` might bail out as soon as it find any of them, whereas `(lower|upper)_bound` have to find the first/last.

Comment: Good point Steve, please ignore my rant. Also note that the result from `lower_bound` can't just be compared to `end`, it might return an iterator to the point where an insertion would go so you have to check if the item actually matches the search criteria. I have my own short wrapper function that does this.